# Calculating User Counts with Common Entities

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to determine groups of users who have common interests.

#### Data Model and Characteristics

- **User** and **Interest** are node labels and represent unique nodes
- **LIKES** is the relationship among them, (User)-[:LIKES]->(Interest)
- All properties of nodes are indexed
- Relation nature can be characterized as many to many between the nodes
- There are 300+ interests and 120,000+ users

I used the following query to determine user count with one common interest and all others;

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:LIKES]-(i:Interest)
WHERE i.name = "Baking"
WITH u
MATCH (u)-[:LIKES]-(i:Interest)
WHERE i.name <> "Baking"
RETURN i.name, COUNT(u) AS userCount
ORDER BY userCount DESC
```

I tried making a query which can have 3 common interests but that made it slower. I think this is not a good, scallable design, can anyone help?

Though maybe its not plausible but the end goal is to calculate nxn combinations of interests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should limit the interests and only take the top five or something?
Also i don't know your data model but is the interest a unique node. That would speed up the query. So the relation [has interest]->( baking) points to the same node and you just can start from baking to get all the users. 
Maybe flip your query and start from interest (cypher is strange) or you can force the query to  use indexes

Comment: There should be at least 5 most common groups of interests with users. And yes, each interest is a unique node and I am using indexes.

Comment: Also you can use USING INDEX x:Interest(name) if he did not use index. 

 you can also use explain and profile to see the query plan.
how do you use 3 common interest?

Comment: What query do you use  for the 3 common interest?
i would do something like Match(interest1)-[]->(user1),(interest2)-[]->(user1),(interest3)-[]->(user1)

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I'll try profiling the query, thanks for the tip.